# Where do I put this statement 'setJMenuBar(menuBar);'?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jmenu

Main Class:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Main extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame  = new JFrame("Checking Account Actions");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    CheckingAccountActions panel = new CheckingAccountActions();

    MyWindowAdapter winAdapter = new MyWindowAdapter(panel);
    frame.addWindowListener(winAdapter);

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

} // Main()

class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter {
private CheckingAccountActions saved;

public MyWindowAdapter(CheckingAccountActions saved) {
    this.saved = saved;
}

// in your window closing method
// check the state of checkActions first before doing anything
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    // note -- don't check for saved in a static way
    // use a method on the instance.
    if(!saved.saved) {
        String  message = "The data in the application is not saved.\n"
                        + "Would you like to save it before exiting the
                                            +  application?";
        int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, message);

        if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            CheckingAccountActions.chooseFile(2);
    }

    JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();
    frame.setVisible(false);

    // Main.frame.setVisible(false);
    System.exit(0);
}

} // MyWindowAdapter()
```

This class, as you see, extends JPanel and this is where my Menu items are initialized, but do I use Main class for this statement 'setJMenuBar(menuBar);', since it gives an error in CheckingAccountActions because JFrame is in MAIN.

CheckingAccountActions class:

```
public class CheckingAccountActions extends JPanel {
// Panel
private JLabel         message;

// Menu
private JMenuBar           menuBar;

private JMenu          File;
private JMenuItem      Read, Write;

private JMenu          Account;
private JMenuItem      NewAccount, ListAccounts, ListChecks, ListDeposits, FindAccount;

private JMenu          Transactions;
private JMenuItem      AddTransactions;

// code...
//
//
// code...

public CheckingAccountActions() {


//************************** PANEL *****************************************
// JLabel
    message = new JLabel("Please choose one of the items: ");
    message.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 15));

    CheckingAccountActionsListener listener = new CheckingAccountActionsListener();

//************************** MENU ******************************************
// Menu
    File  = new JMenu("File");
// MenuItem
    Read  = new JMenuItem("Read from file");
    Write = new JMenuItem("Write to file");
// ActionListener
    Read.addActionListener(listener);
    Write.addActionListener(listener);
// Add Buttons to Menu
    File.add(Read);
    File.add(Write);

// Menu
    Account = new JMenu("Account");
// MenuItem
    NewAccount   = new JMenuItem("Add new account");
    ListAccounts = new JMenuItem("List accounts transaction");
    ListChecks   = new JMenuItem("List all checks");
    ListDeposits = new JMenuItem("List all deposits");
    FindAccount  = new JMenuItem("Find an account");
// ActionListener
    NewAccount.addActionListener(listener);
    ListAccounts.addActionListener(listener);
    ListChecks.addActionListener(listener);
    ListDeposits.addActionListener(listener);
    FindAccount.addActionListener(listener);
// Add Buttons to Menu
    Account.add(NewAccount);
    Account.add(ListAccounts);
    Account.add(ListChecks);
    Account.add(ListDeposits);
    Account.add(FindAccount);


// Menu
    Transactions = new JMenu("Transactions");
// MenuItem
    AddTransactions = new JMenuItem("Add Transactions");
// ActionListener
    AddTransactions.addActionListener(listener);
// Add Buttons to Menu
    Transactions.add(AddTransactions);

// MenuBar
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(File);
    menuBar.add(Account);
    menuBar.add(Transactions);

    setBackground(Color.white);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240, 250));
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}

private class CheckingAccountActionsListener implements ActionListener {

// code...

}
```

Edit: what I am confused about is how to add my MenuBar to the Frame while the Frame is in another class?

FINAL EDIT: I got it working. I just moved all my JFrame components to CheckingAccountActions class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). The `MenuDemo` example will show you one way to structure your program.

It also shows you the proper way to create your GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: Hey in the link you provided, it shows me this line at the end 'frame.setJMenuBar(theJMenuBar);'. Since my Main class extends JFrame, all I need is 'setJMenuBar' but in the link, the program structure is not the same as mine, its 1 whole program with JFrame part of it. Mine is seperate, so how can I make Main class accept my menuBar? How do I pass it to Main?

Comment: That is the point of the tutorial. It shows you how to better structure your program. Follow the tutorial example and you won't have a problem. You should not have application logic in your main method, other than to create an display the frame.

Answer (score 2):

`setJMenuBar(menubar)` is not what you actually looking for. If you want to set the menubar to your frame, just add the menu bar to the frame with the method `add(menuBar)`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! So, what I am wondering is, I just add (menuBar) in the Main program? That also gives me an error, what I am confused about is how to add my MenuBar to the Frame while the Frame is in another class?

Comment: You should add menuBar in frame only. and not in `JPanel`

Comment: -1, a frame has a special location for the menu bar and you should be using the `setJMenuBar(...)` method. @EdoIsa, Read the tutorial. I gave you a link!

Comment: Yes but that gives an error because menuBar is initialized in CheckingAccountActions. Should I initialize menuBar in Main and leave the rest in CheckingAccountActions? Or should I move ALL the Menu items to Main?

Comment: @EdoIsa You can move all the menuItems to the Frame. It will add the menu bar while loading a frame.

Comment: @Prasad: So I am moving that entire page full of declarations and initialization of menu items and buttons into Main, correct?

Comment: @EdoIsa no you just need to shift entire `MenuBar` code like declarations, initializations to Frame. Keep rest of the code same.

Comment: @Prasad: I moved everything, I am getting an error now because;

1. Listener class isn't here so now what ....
2. menuBar(File);  - and similar initializations dont work because 'File' is in CheckingAccountActions.

Comment: @EdoIsa okay.

1. You should know that you have to add Listener class to perform an action. 


2. what is **file** in **menuBar(File)**? will you please update the code above?